# HDF5 file is loaded multiple times when training dataset using Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, hdf5

I am training a dataset using hdf5 files and the log says the hdf5 file is loaded 3 times. I was wondering why is that?

For training I am using `4 GPUs`

```
0830 10:51:06.050088 24335 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:79] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: /train_h5_list.txt
I0830 10:51:06.055855 24336 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:79] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: /train_h5_list.txt
I0830 10:51:06.066175 24335 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 8259
I0830 10:51:06.071753 24336 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 8259
I0830 10:51:06.878861 24337 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:79] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: /train_h5_list.txt
I0830 10:51:06.900501 24337 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 8259
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have found out is that if you use multiple `GPUs` the `hdf5` files are loaded multiple times for each GPU! This can result in problems tho and I would not recommend using multiple `GPUs` when training with `hdf5` files